# Twilio Flow the widget looks like Liquid variables %H

Tags: variables, time, twilio, hour, twilio-flow

I am trying to get the current hour of the day using date: "%H" in a set variables widget. I do the this first on day of month (date: "%d") which works okay, but the hour doesn't appear to return any value, any suggestions?

Basically, trying to compensate for the time difference in UK and US, using 'now'.

[image: image loaded here.]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your widget to show how you're using it?

Comment: Basically, I am in the UK and trying to compensate for the US 'PDT' time in the 'now' function for the current date.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot I can see one use of `%H` in which you set a `time_zone` variable to `{{ 'now' | date: " %H %M " }}`. I can then see you are comparing that `time_zone` variable as a time.

When you compare as a time in Studio you need to provide the time in the form "HH:MM", but it seems you have it in the format " HH MM ".

Try setting the variable to be `{{ 'now' | date: "%H:%M" }}` and see if things work.

Comment: Thanks for this but it seems to be allocating it as a string of characters to the variable from the pipe character to the closing quote.

Comment: I am going on vacation this evening, so I have sorted the problem by saying today's message is available after 8am each morning. Many thanks for your considerations.

Comment: Glad it's sorted in the meantime. I was able to set the various date formats correctly in my own Studio Flow, so I don't know what's going on with yours. You might find it easier to open a ticket with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) who could take a look at your Flow and help out.

Comment: When I get back when I will have time to investigate further. I checked today and the work-a-round is functioning fine.

Comment: Good stuff, would love to help more if I can when you’re back.

Comment: I got a very complex answer to the ticket, basically telling it is a time zone problem with now, and have given a number of solutions I need to unpack, one using a function. But I'm away now so I'll get back to it.